# What's a single word for a situation where a person swears a lot?

Tags: single-word-requests

It is not a commonly used word. 
It's not a medical condition, but it's a noun that describes a person or the condition of a person who abuses when he is angry and calms down. I think it starts with an m.

Comment: _Foul-mouthed_ is a common word for this.

Comment: You mean **muck-spout**? Here's the link: [offensive language - What do you call a person who uses vulgar words too often? - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343917/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-uses-vulgar-words-too-often)

Comment: A single? As opposed to an LP? Surely not?

Comment: [Hothead](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hothead)?

Comment: ...a New Yorker?

Comment: In a rage? A duplicate, though.

Comment: Could you be thinking of Tourette's Syndrome? It's a neurological disorder that causes someone to blurt out words, and in many cases they're expletives. But it doesn't have anything to do with anger.

Comment: "[A] person or the condition of a person who abuses when he is angry and calms down" may be defined as a "typical Twitter user".